# Running a different configuration.nix file into a virtual machine from a non-nixos operating system

Tags: virtual-machine, nixos, container

In the amazing [nixos](https://nixos.org/), it is possible to launch a lightweight container that will run a system whose `configuration.nix` file is different from the host configuration by first compiling using:

```
$ nixos-rebuild build-vm -I nixos-config=./configuration.nix
```

and running via:

```
$ ./result/bin/run-*-vm
```

However, the first command cannot work on operating systems where nixos is not installed, like debian + [nixpkgs](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/download.html), because `nixos-rebuild` does not exists.

How can I still use `build-vm` in non-nixos systems?

Comment: I believe this just builds the config rather than runs? Perhaps the title could be changed.

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski well you can easily run the VM once it's built using something like `./result/bin/run-*-vm`. Building without running may not be that interesting (except when you only want to check if it builds), that's why I was interested to actually run the VM. I'll edit the question to make it clear.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks to `clever` and `infinisil`:

```
nix-build '<nixpkgs/nixos>' -A vm -I nixos-config=./configuration.nix
```

Comment: You can mark your answer as accepted since this is, well, the right answer

Comment: Keep in mind that such `nix-build` invocation is dependent on `$NIX_PATH` environment variable, specifically `nixpkgs` path. So it can produce different results. You can use `NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/8f9022789211d6be645e5f97a258e0b6e9e24c9e.tar.gz nix-build ...` or `nix-build -I nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/8f9022789211d6be645e5f97a258e0b6e9e24c9e.tar.gz ...` for deterministic builds. Or use nix flakes which avoids the issue.